# Google Maps Place API - SKU: Autocomplete (included with Places Details) – Per Session

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating an app that allows the user to search a specific location within Google Maps.. after finding their location, will I (developer) get charged for this or will their be a fee?

Comment: seems like they start new billing system https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#ac-no-details-session it is really interesting since i using google places sdk for free now limited to 1000 queries a day, would like to hear more info

Comment: Do you use Places API web service or Places API for Android?